# find different values in two dataframes exported to and imported from the same CSV

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, comparison

I have a `df_final` pandas v1.3.4 dataframe and am exporting it to a CSV file so I don't need to repeat the dataframe building step every time I do an analysis.  `df_final` will be a 13000 x 91 dataframe, but I am testing the process on a smaller 689x91 dataframe first.

I would like to confirm that the `df_final_csv` dataframe generated by reading in the `df_final` CSV is the same as the `df_final` dataframe.  Based on the below, it looks like they are different.  However, I'm not sure how.  I copied some stack overflow code (below, adapted from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53607488/11357695)) but some other solutions ([eg](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48647840/11357695)) dont work as I have list objects in my `df_final`. How can I find what value(s) are causing the issue?

If any other information would help please let me know.

```
#689 rows x 91 columns
df_final = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(results)                                
print (f'NaN are present:  {df_final.isnull().values.any()}')# False

#export to csv
df_final.to_csv('integrated_df.csv')

#read in csv
df_final_csv = pd.read_csv('integrated_df.csv', index_col = 0)
print (f' NaN are present:  {df_final_csv .isnull().values.any()}')# False')
print (f'imported df is same as exported df:  {df_final.equals(df_final_csv)}')#False 

#try and find discrepancies (--> empty df)     
different_values = df_final_csv [~df_final_csv .isin(df_final)].dropna() #empty df with only column headers
```

Cheers!

Comment: `pd.read_csv` may not restore the same data types. So your integers and floats may still appear as strings. You'd have to call `.astype` and set the types for `df_final_csv` before doing any comparisons. Also, you may want to consider using `pickle` which would preserve the types. [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62222676/1520594) an answer that can help you decide if pickle is appropriate.

Comment: Maybe there are some special characters which CSV messed up. try to write in .pkl file, you'll get 100% same data. `import pickle; pickle.dump(df, open("df.pkl", 'wb')); # then read it ; df_new = pickle.load(open("df.pkl", 'rb'))`

Comment: Hi both, thanks for your replies.  Both were useful and algrebe your link was really relevant but Amir's is the code I used to fix the actual problem, so @Amir saleem if you make your comment an answer I'll accept it (as I'm pretty sure I can't accept both).  Thanks again to you both!

Comment: Thank you @TimKirkwood, I posted it at an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe there are some special characters which CSV messed up. try to write in .pkl file, you'll get 100% same data.

```
import pickle
# write into pickle file
pickle.dump(df, open("df.pkl", 'wb'))

# then read it
df_new = pickle.load(open("df.pkl", 'rb'))
```